# Let $t = f(x)$ be the solution of the equation $t^5 + t = x$. Evaluate $ \int_0^2 f(x) \ dx$.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, definite-integrals

Let $t = f(x)$ be the solution of the equation.

$t^5 + t = x$

Find $\int_0^2 f(x)\ dx$.

Answer: $\dfrac{4}{3}$

Answer (score 3):

Yes,  $4/3$ is correct.

We can change the integral to $$\int_0^2 f(x) dx = \int_0^1 t (5t^4 + 1) dt = \frac{4}{3}$$

Here,  I changed $dx$ to $( 5t^4 + 1) dt$ and the limits of integrations are real solutions of $t^5 + t = 0$ and $t^5 + t = 2$ respectively which turn out to be $0$ and $1$.

Answer (score 1):

$g(t) = t^5 + t$

$g(t) = f^{-1}(t)$

$g(t)$ is continuous and monotonic and hence invertable.  And $g(t) = f^{-1}(t)$

The area under the curve $f(x)$ equals the area above curve $g(t)$ but below the bounds of $x.$

$g(0) = 0\\
g(1) = 2$

$\int_0^2 f(x) \ dx = \int_0^1 2 - g(t) \ dt$

Answer (score 0):

If $x = t^5 + t$ and the limits are $0$ and $2$, what will the limits be in terms of $t$?

$t^5+t=0 \Rightarrow t_l=$ lower limit

$t^5+t=2 \Rightarrow t_u=$ upper limit

And if $f(x) = t^5 +t$

what will $dx$ be?

Find the limits and the substitution of $dx$ in terms of $dt$ and solve the integral in terms of $t$.